# Remove default column separator in sap.ui.table.table

Tags: sapui5

I would like to remove the default column separator in sap.ui.table.Table

anyone please help !

[image: it comes as]

[image: my requirment is]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I did it like this:** I added the class `noColumBorder` to the table where I wanted to be no separator to be visible. The class name can be different, of course.

In CSS I added this:

```
.noColumnBorder .sapUiTableTr>td {
    border-right: 0 !important;
}
```